# How do I access previous state and use it to update only some object properties in a single state setter call?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I was previously updating state like this:

```js
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(callLength);
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(callLength);
  setCurrentTime(current);
  setTimeLeft(prevState => prevState - 1000);
```

But this causes two renders. So I have merged these properties in to one object so I only need to do one state update:

```js
  const [timeData, setTimeData] = useState({
    currentTime: callLength,
    timeLeft: callLength,
  });
```

But my attempt to access previous state is now not working in the same way:

```
setTimeData(prevState => {currentTime: current, timeLeft: prevState.timeLeft - 1000 });
```

This throws a linter error. What it the correct syntax to use to access previous state and update an object property in state using the pervious state as the basis for that update?

Comment: what linter error do you get ?

Comment: `';' expected.` highlighted under the colon at the end of `timeLeft`

Comment: Yeah saw the issue, posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state setter expect an object

try this:

```
setTimeData(prevState => ({ currentTime: current, timeLeft: prevState.timeLeft - 1000 }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your callback that's passed in `setTimeData` returns void instead of state.

```js
setTimeData(prevState => {currentTime: current, timeLeft: prevState.timeLeft - 1000 });
```

You should type:

```js
setTimeData(prevState => ({ currentTime: current, timeLeft: prevState.timeLeft - 1000 }));
```

Or

```js
setTimeData(prevState => {
  return { currentTime: current, timeLeft: prevState.timeLeft - 1000 };
});
```